# How do i check and get my own methods value in OAuth2 .net WebApi2 application instead of Userid and password

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get and check values from database , don't want to use existing function like below .
 public override async Task

```
GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
               OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
```

i want to check my own method and parameter instead of this method `ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);`

Example: `var user = await myclass.CheckResource(MAC,SerialNO, ProductKey);`

Could you please suggest how to change it and return Token?

Comment: What eactly is it that you object to? Using the OWIN classes? You're saying that instead of doing it as shown, you want to write it yourself - but without knowing why, you'll only get an implementation that does exactly the same thing? https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application